# Is it possible to filter on multiple message types on one subscription using Azure Service Bus and MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

We are currently using Azure Service Bus where all messages are sent to a single Topic - each receiving system has a corresponding Subscription to the topic and filters are added to the subscription to indicate which messages should be consumed.

This keeps the service bus configuration very simple, i.e. 1 topic, multiple subscriptions, multiple filters per subscription.

We are looking into using MassTransit to take advantage of sagas etc. but would like to move to MassTransit for all messaging instead of having multiple libraries to publish a message.

I don't seem to be able to replicate what we currently have set up in Azure Service Bus with MassTransit - I have been able to work around a few issues so far but now I'm struggling to create multiple filters (RuleOptions) on a subscription via MassTransit.

Is this possible or do I have to bite the bullet and reconfigure my Azure Service Bus configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The complexity (and potential bottleneck) of pushing everything through a single topic with multiple subscriptions using filters seems more complex and frail than using the default MassTransit topology. MassTransit designed the use of Azure Service Bus intentionally with out-of-the-box conventions that just work.

Trying to shoehorn and existing approach into it may be possible, but isn't something I'd want to support down the road due to the filter-based approach and everything being tied to a single topic.

Also, without delayed abandon, delaying redelivery on topic subscriptions is not possible, so you're stuck with immediately retrying failed messages within a subscription, blocking the subscriptions "queue" until you get the message out of there.

Comment: We went down the single Topic and Subscription with filters route so we could scale out our downstream services whilst maintaining ordered delivery.

e.g. two users update and delete the same record in quick succession, resulting in two different events hitting the bus, because we scale out our downstream services we need to use sessions so only one instance has the lock on that session id (based for example on the record id). We couldn't allow multiple instances of the downstream service to publish the events as that couldn't guarantee order.

Would MassTransit support that scenario?

Comment: MassTransit supports session-based receivers, yes.

Comment: Chris do you have an example of how you would enforce ordering over multiple message types in a scaled out infrastructure? I've watched numerous videos, read the documentation, looked at the code etc. but I can't see how this is handled out of the box.

I am using Azure Service Bus so can utilize the sessions functionality so would have a sticky subscriber but if the session is on the subscription and we have a subscription per message type then we obviously lose the ordering.

Comment: @GaryF sounds like something you'd need to connect with developer support to work through.